# how to make underline use Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, iphone, xcode

[sample text image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWHO0.png)

**I want to draw underline like picture.
but "NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName" is not working
please help me**

Comment: You would need to literally draw the line yourself. TextKit can help.

Comment: ...or just an `UIImage` below your `UILabel`.

Comment: If you want custom underline "rendering" with NSAttributedString, you'll need to override some methods and use TextKit. Else, depending on what's the object/final use, you could use additional images...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do this using [NSAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring)

Example :

```
 let underlineAttribute = [NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.thick.rawValue]
 let underlineAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "StringWithUnderLine", attributes: underlineAttribute)
 YourLabel.attributedText = underlineAttributedString
```

**Extension**

```
extension UILabel {
func underline() {
    if let textString = self.text {
      let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textString)
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle,
                                      value: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue,
                                      range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length))
      attributedText = attributedString
    }
}
}
```